# Delete all spaces+newlines but the first

Tags: whitespace

Given the following buffer:

```
foo bar

    nee nope
```

If I place point on the 2nd line and execute

```
(just-one-space -1)
```

the result will be:

```
foo bar nee nope
```

Is there a way to modify the behavior such that the newline after 'bar' will be kept, e.g. with this result:

```
foo bar
neee nope
```

?

Or do I have to write my own function for this?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: I do not use this package ([`shrink-whitespace`](https://github.com/jcpetkovich/shrink-whitespace.el)), but you can check it out to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Instead of updating the question, you can add your own answer and mark it as a solution that worked for you. That way this question will have a clean closure.

Answer (score 1):

The command `delete-blank-lines` (bound to `C-x C-o` by default) does what you want, at least in this case.  Of course, it doesn't act like `just-one-space` in other cases, so you may want to write a function that dispatches appropriately for your preferences.

Comment: `delete-blank-lines` will not remove the leading whitespace, so you still need a couple commands (e.g. `delete-blank-lines` and `delete-horizontal-space`). In the OP's specific example I'd probably put point at the beginning of`neee` and hit `C-^`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wrote something myself, see updated question above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
  (defun viking--kill-space()
  "Kill space around point, including newline(s), but the first."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((lineA 0) (lineB 0)
         (beg (save-excursion
                (skip-chars-backward " \t\r\n")
                (cond ((looking-at "\r\n")
                       (forward-char 2))
                      ((looking-at "\n")
                       (forward-char 1)))
                (setq lineA (line-number-at-pos))
                (point)))
         (end (save-excursion
                (skip-chars-forward " \t\r\n")
                (setq lineB (line-number-at-pos))
                (point)))
         )
    (viking--blink-region beg end)
    (if (= lineA lineB)
        (just-one-space)
      (delete-region beg end))
    (message "spaces cleared")))
```

This accomplishes the job, it could a little bit more efficient though.